# Git: how to replace ANSI colors for diff with arbitrary characters?

Tags: git, markdown, git-config

I want to save the output of

```
git diff HEAD^1 --word-diff=color
```

in a markdown file such that the "old" word(s) be marked `~~old~~` resulting in <del>old</del>new once converted to HTML.

Of course, it is not much of hurdle to pipe the output through a script that would replace the ANSI escape codes with whatever I need. However, I'd like to check, if there is an option to somehow configure it in git itself. An attempt to just specify the characters I need in git config results in error, and not surprisingly so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that adding the following line to the `[alias]` section of your *.gitconfig* will do what you want on a linux system:

```
diffmd = "!f() { git diff --word-diff=plain $1 |  sed 's/{+//g' | sed 's/+}//g'  | sed 's/\\[-/~~/g'  | sed 's/-\\]/~~/g' ; } ; f"
```

You would then use it as  `git diffmd HEAD^`.

---

Explanation:

Here we are basically wrapping the defining and calling of a bash function in a git alias.

The `git diff` option `--word-diff=plain` replaces the ANSI colour changes with strings "[-" , "-]", "{+" and "+}".

The "$1" is substituted with "HEAD^" in this use case.

We use sed to replace "[-" and "-]" with "~~", and to replace "{+" and "+}" with nothing.

Comment: Of course if any of those strings appear in the *content* of your diffs, then you can see this will lead to problems. In which case maybe you would better off sticking to the coloured output, and replacing the sed commands with commands which replace the escape codes with your markdown strings.

Comment: I've accepted the answer. However, it is essentially equivalent to piping through an additional program. Piping would be more flexible, I think. But thank you anyway.